# How can I edit a webpage in the browser and it saves html to the server

Tags: html, browser, content-management-system, editor

Is there something that would allow me to edit (text only is fine) my webpages in the browser then apply that edit to the html on my server?  I am running on Apache but can switch to IIS if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for a CMS.
If you create a website with a CMS, you can login to the site and edit and manage content on the fly.

The popular ones are Drupal, Joomla, Magento, Typo3, Wordpress.

Each has it's own pros and cons, thou I would suggest Wordpress for beginners.

http://wordpress.org/download/

You need zero coding background to begin too.

Comment: Sorry, I think I need to be more specific.  What I have now is a handcoded html/css website and what I want to do is to be able to edit text in my webpage from my browser, then the change is applied to the html file directly on the server.  I was hoping perhaps there is simply some script I can add to my page to be able to do this rather than having to setup a whole CMS and database?

Comment: That will not work, since there are many factors involved such as authentication. Without this, anyone can edit your website. The effort required to build such a foolproof system is more compared to migrating your site to a CMS.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking to edit the code of the website? If so, http://ftplive.com/ is the thing for you. That's assuming you have the FTP info for the site/server.